# React Native Background Color property is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, stylesheet

I am having problem while changing the background color of View in React Native, `backgroundColor` property is working fine in other elements except in my Footer Element.

In the [Image Snapshot](https://ibb.co/19cgTRw) you can see White color in those two top borders of Footer Element. How to remove that white color from there

```
</View>

        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footer}>

        </View>
</View>

footer:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        height:80,
        borderTopLeftRadius:20,
        borderTopRightRadius:20,
        backgroundColor:"black",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your footer with another View which has the same background as your top View component.

Like this:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "orange"}}>
  <View style={styles.footer}>
  ...
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use**

```
return (
    <View style={styles.gridItem}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={props.onSelect}>
        <View style={styles.container} >
          <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
            {props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CategoryGridTitle;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridItem: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 15,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 3,
    padding: 15,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    backgroundColor: '#ff6f00'
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: "open-sans-bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "right",
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the prop below to make the background red in react-native-elements.

```
buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
```

You should edit the styling of a button in react-native-elements using the prop buttonStyle .

Here is the working code. The button is red in here.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
            title='Login' 
            buttonStyle={{
              backgroundColor:'red'
            }}
            />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working code, https://snack.expo.io/BkRgH0_HE

Comment: I am not asking about styling button.Please see the snapshot which i have added above for everyone's reference

Comment: Is not that a border-radius?

Comment: That footer element is above Orange Container,So after giving border radius in footer element the remaining space should be Orange from top left and right border but it is showing white.